# How to correct a qgis2web-generated Web map jumping around when hovering on waypoints to display photo as pop-up

Tags: mousehover

I am using qgis2web (v. 3.17.1) with QGIS v.3.34.0-Prizren to generate a map where waypoints can be hovered over to display an image as a pop up. All is good except that the map is randomly jumping around as I move my mouse above it, especially when the mouse pointer is in the vicinity of a waypoint, and even though there would be plenty of room to display the pop up without moving the map.

I switched from "canvas size" to "full screen" in Export to web map/Appearance/Template with only a little improvement, but the erratic movements start again once I am zoomed in. What other parameter should I try to adjust to stabilize the map layer?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just found out that if Scale/Zoom / Extent (qgis2web Export menu, last item at bottom) is changed from "Canvas extent" to "Fit to layers extent", the behaviour stops and the mouse navigation does not trigger the map to move erratically any longer... Problem solved...!